# Restrict number of Components on Page

Tags: presentation

We need to enforce a rule where a specific component can only come once on specific Page template. Can some body guide me how do I implement this we are using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2.

Is there any out of the box of rule in Sitecore Rule engine instead of Pipeline fix as mentioned in this link

[Is it possible to limit Renderings so they can only be placed once on a page?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/is-it-possible-to-limit-renderings-so-they-can-only-be-placed-once-on-a-page)

Comment: I guess you could try to write validator for renderings field - validator would check number of renderings. Check this link: 
[creating a custom field validator in sitecore](https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2016/creating-a-custom-field-validator-in-sitecore)

Comment: Feel free to add additional answers to the linked question. Raising new duplicate questions to get additional answers is not really the way to go about it.