# Is it possible to disable a rendering after it has been chosen in the Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor, rendering-parameters

as the title suggests, I would like to know if it's possible to disable the selection of a specific rendering in the experience editor after it has been chosen.

[image]

For instance after I have chosen and added SearchForm, is there a way to disable it so it cannot be chosen or added to the page anymore.

Comment: Not easily. You should strive hard to not try and make the CMS do the editor's work for them with imposing limits such as this.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will deviate from this plan.

Comment: Agree with Mark but try the answers here if it is a definite requirement: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/is-it-possible-to-limit-renderings-so-they-can-only-be-placed-once-on-a-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to limit Renderings so they can only be placed once on a page?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/is-it-possible-to-limit-renderings-so-they-can-only-be-placed-once-on-a-page)

Comment: That does look a little like what I would like. I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to handle this. You can implement a custom patch, but make sure you're covering all cases for all applications like Experience Editor, Content Editor, and Horizon, etc.
I think that BrainJocks SCORE can handle this, it provides additional Sitecore Rules that can help you with such scenarios.